# Remove the "open" button in save file dialog (IE only)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, savefiledialog

I use the following code to generate a save file dialog:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/test.html"), true);
Response.End();
```

Works as intended. However, I would like to remove the "open" button, so I just get the "save as" and "cancel". Is there any way to generate another kind of dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

```
<META name="DownloadOptions" content="noopen"/>
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thanks for mentioning it. In my case its enough though

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible (in a cross-browser way) and **this is a good thing**.
It's solely the user's decision if the file should be saved in a folder he specifies or in the temporary folder of the system (and then be opened automatically).

However, for HTML files I see your point...

Answer (score 0):

There is a new way to do this using the ["download" attribute on an](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download)  which when a blank value will simply trigger the download. This however [does not work in IE.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) But it could be used in conjunction with the meta tag.